# Node.js API protected by Keycloak with Access-Type "bearer-only"

Tags: node.js, keycloak, bearer-token, keycloak-connect

I am new to Keycloak. I have created the simples app in Node.js as per the documentation:

```
import express from "express";
import Keycloak from "keycloak-connect";

const keycloak = new Keycloak({});
const app = express();
app.use( keycloak.middleware());

app.get('/api', keycloak.protect(), function(req, res){
    res.send("This is API!");
 });
 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("Server is up!");
 });
 
 app.listen(3000);
```

My `keycloak.json` looks like follwing

```
{
    "clientId": "mydemoapp-api",
    "bearerOnly": true,
    "serverUrl": "http://mykeycloakserver:8180/auth",
    "realm": "myrealm",
    "realmPublicKey":"MIIBIjANBgk... "
}
```

The Access Type of the client mydemoapp-api is set to "confidential". Using Postman or CURL i can generate the token and then access the endpoint /api with it. If I try to connect to /api without token I get access denied - so far so good.

I changed the Access Type to "bearer only" for mydemoapp-api in Keycloak admin. Then I created another client in the same realm mydemoapp-client with Access Type "public"

I have requested a token for client mydemoapp-client using Postman again. Then I used this token to access endpoint /api. But I always get Access denied.

From the documentation I understood that if no roles are specified and no other restriction are activated I should be able to log in to any client in the realm and then use the SSO token to authenticate to any other client in the same realm. But apparently I am missing some piece in the puzzle.

Comment: Please check the example from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/master/example/README.md i suggest you use sso instead of using curl. Also i dont See a protected Ressource in your example

Comment: I am very sorry I have copied a wrong code snippet to the question.  It is fixxed now. I have installed the referenced example. I can log in and log out but the "Protected Resource" link returns "Access denied" as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following blog https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak#test_your_new_client

It suggests setting `Authentication Flow Overrides/Direct Grant Flow` to `direct grant` for `mydemoapp-client`. And it works!

Comment: Hi @jirmed, any idea how it works on changing this flow to `direct grant`. I couldn't find this information in the link you mentioned. Also could you please explain/ answer if you were able to achieve SSO with this ?

Comment: Hi @A.K.47,
the switch is available in Cliints/Settings.  The tooltip says "This enables suport for DirectAccess Grants. which means that client has access to username/password of user and exchange it directly with Keycloak server for access token. In terms of OAuth2
this enables support of 'Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant for this client."
I am not an expert in Keycloak but I reckon that it means that if the switch is on the generated token includes the "resouce owner" that allow the other client can than decode.